# Updating data in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scope

I'm trying to update a data grid made with Vue.js but the content isn't updating properly. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-10">
    <div class="row" id="grid">
        <div class="col-md-4" v-for="entry in entries">
            <div class="info_overlay">
                <div>
                    <span class="name">{{ entry.name }}</span>
                    <span class="description">{{ entry.description }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now this my JS:

```
var _results = [{name: 'toto', description: "titi" }];
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#grid',
  data: {
    entries: _results
  }
})

socket.on('get_entries', function(data){
    console.log(_results); 
    console.log(data);
    // Both logs show the same result (see below)

    _results[0].description = data[0].description    // This works! The description of the 1st item is updated
    _results = data;                                 // This doesn't work

});
```

Now I don't know why it's not possible to update the whole array at once. I do notice in Chrome a slight difference between the logs messages although the data is the same:

- The first one looks like this:
  {…}, **ob**: Se]
  0:
  description: (...)
  name: (...)
- The second one looks more natural: [{…}]
  0:
  description: "A nice pet"
  name: "Test pet"

Is there a difference between these two?

Comment: Yes. There is a difference. `_results` is a global outside of Vue's control, so it's not reactive, while `entries` is part of the application's data, so it is reactive. Note that JavaScript array assignments are by reference, so both `_results` and `entries` reference the same individual objects. That's why changing `_results[0]` also changes `entries[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option:

```js
var _results = [{name: 'toto', description: "titi" }];
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#grid',
  data: {
    entries: _results
  }
})

socket.on('get_entries', function(data){
    console.log(_results); 
    console.log(data);
    // Both logs show the same result (see below)

    _results[0].description = data[0].description    // This works! The description of the 1st item is updated
    _results.splice(0, data.length, ...data);                                // This doesn't work

});
```

Comment: Wow! Now that's pretty neat. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a way to update the entire `array` without the need to do additional `JavaScript` in order to trigger reactivity but use what `Vue` has to offer.

For that, you might need to put `socket` into `created()` hook with an `arrow function`, so we can use `this` to update `entries`.

That way we trigger the reactivity on `data` property directly.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
var _results = [{name: 'toto', description: "titi" }];
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#grid',
  data: {
    entries: _results,
    socket: io()
  },
  created() { 
   this.socket.on('get_entries', (data) => {  
    this.entries = data;                                 
   });
  }
})
```

Does that work in your case as well?

Comment: I couldn't use "this" because the update is done in the socket callback function so the scope is different.

Comment: You could use an arrow function instead to change the scope. I will edit my answer shortly.

Comment: What does "this" refer to in this case?

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't work because as I suspected, "entries" is undefined in this case.

Comment: Can you try the edited code, do you still get `undefined`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you please let me know if the above code works in your case? Thanks.